# Count & Highlight Table Row Elements Dynamically

Tags: php, jquery

I want to be able to do two things.  The first, is look at all "selected" items of a certain value.  Say I have a, b, c ; I want to look for all items selected as "c" and highlight that table row as a different color.  In addition, upon opening the form, I want the items counted, and be able to display a message div at the top of the screen showing those highlighted items.  What is the best practical way of doing this? This is my original code :

```
    //Start loop of items
       <?php foreach ( $data['Detail'] as $key=>$item){?>
        <tr id="tr_<?php echo $key+1?>">
            <td>
                <select value="<?php echo $location; ?>" name="[<?php echo $key;?>][location]" id="location_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control>
                    <option value="Selection1" <?= ($item['location']) == 'Selection1' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Selection1</option>
                    <option value="Selection2" <?= ($item['location']) == 'Selection2' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Selection2</option>
                    <option value="Selection3" <?= ($item['location']) == 'Selection3' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Selection3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
// Segment here to count? Example :
// $location_count = 0; If $location = 'c' then $location_count++;
    <?php } ?>
```

Sample Div Code :

```
<div>
<p>You have <?php echo $location_count?> Locations that need reviewed</p>
</div>
```

Image Sample of Working Code :
[image: Sample Working Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the theory is:

- loop through the `table`'s `select` elements
- check each `select`'s value and update the row style
- when a select changes, do the same to the current row.
- count the rows with the highlight
- append the row count to the div

You can see the theory in practice with the code/link below.
The code is purposefully simplistic for demonstration and could be improved for performance/terseness. However it's not *bad* code :)

```js
$(function() {

  /* function to run for select boxes in table */
  
  function rowState( $select ) {

    var selected = false;
    
    /* set boolean for selected */
    
    if ( $select.val() === "c" ) {
      selected = true;
    }
    
    /* apply css class to the row if selected */
    
    $select.closest("tr").toggleClass("c", selected);
    
    /* count rows */
    
    var n = $( "table tr.c" ).length;
    
    /* change the html element's text to the count */
    
    $( ".snippet span" ).text( n );

  }

  $("table select").each(function() {
    
    /* on page load, set selected states */
    
    rowState($(this));
    
  }).on("change", function() {
    
    /* on state change, set selected states */
    
    rowState($(this));
    
  });




});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr td {
  background: #eee;
}
tr.c td {
  background: #cfc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="snippet">
  Please review <span>x</span> items
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="a" selected>a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c" selected>c</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b" selected>b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for one of the most descriptive and helpful answers I have ever gotten on SO!  I assume the top code tidbit is jquery, the language that I want to learn more about next.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's `jQuery`... the question was tagged with `jQuery` so I assumed it was OK to use :) -- hope the code comments are helpful.

Comment: Do you have any good references for learning jQuery?  Books, good websites, etc...

Comment: BTW, in the <span> you have "x" where the items are, but in your jQuery snippet it is labelled as "n"?  how does that work?

Comment: `x` is just a placeholder, you should populate that from the PHP when the page is rendered if you can! :)